# How do I make two controls each occupy half their parent's area?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, vcl

I have an application that has a sidebar attached to it (`TPanel` --> `alRight`), that uses a CategoryPanel (`alClient`) inside of it. This CategoryPanel has exactly 2 Groups which are non aligned. I would like to share the boundary of these 2 groups so it would fill up the whole panel space in a 50/50 ratio. Unfortunately The CategoryGroups do not support alignment in designtime, which forces me to run my application every time I want to test it. I tried to set each CategoryGroup to the height to half of the panel, but it displays scrollbars. (See Picture 2)

How can I align/share the boundary in a ratio of 50/50 properly?

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Comment: What do you want to happen when the category groups are closed up?

Comment: If they get collapsed, nothing should happen, the size just remains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your comments, you want to run this code:

```
procedure TForm1.UpdateGroupHeights;
begin
  if not CategoryPanel1.Collapsed then
    CategoryPanel1.Height := CategoryPanelGroup1.ClientHeight div 2;
  if not CategoryPanel2.Collapsed then
    CategoryPanel2.Height := CategoryPanelGroup1.ClientHeight -
      CategoryPanelGroup1.ClientHeight div 2;
end;
```

whenever anything changes that you wish to affect the layout of your groups. So I think you need to call this function from the following events:

- The `OnCreate` event of the form.
- The `OnResize` event of the `TCategoryPanelGroup`.
- The `OnCollapse` and `OnExpand` events of the two category panels.

That looks a bit weird though when one panel is collapsed, and the other is expanded. Personally I'd rejig the code to fill all available space.

```
if not CategoryPanel1.Collapsed then
  ;//nothing to do
if CategoryPanel1.Collapsed and not CategoryPanel2.Collapsed then
  CategoryPanel2.Height := CategoryPanelGroup1.ClientHeight-CategoryPanel1.Height;
if not CategoryPanel1.Collapsed and CategoryPanel2.Collapsed then
  CategoryPanel1.Height := CategoryPanelGroup1.ClientHeight-CategoryPanel2.Height;
if not CategoryPanel1.Collapsed and not CategoryPanel2.Collapsed then
begin
  CategoryPanel1.Height := CategoryPanelGroup1.ClientHeight div 2;
  CategoryPanel2.Height := CategoryPanelGroup1.ClientHeight-CategoryPanel1.Height;
end;
```

Comment: Totally forgot about ClientHeight! Thank you very much.